# Dealing with "Rasterize Paint" lag on mobile when using css3: opacity transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a project where users go back and forth between modals. I'm trying to do this by css transitioning opacity from 0 to 1. However, I noticed something is going very slow with my transitions.

I am getting about a 900ms to 2,000ms lag delay with some of my transitions, so I hooked up my phone to my laptop using chromes remote dev tools https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging and started recording performance events https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/timeline

This is an image of the recorded events fired from the phone. The yellow block is the jQuery click event handler firing, the yellow stripes belong to a jQuery.animate() function. However that green block at the bottom is almost 2 seconds long and it's labeled "Rasterize Paint". The purple slivers on the right are the actual animation taking place.
(EDIT: The jquery.animate() is different from the css animation taking place at the same time. I am adding a class in the event handler that changes opacity of an element that has `transition: opacity 300ms` set)

[image: image of the recorded click event]

What does 'Rasterize Paint' mean? Why does this take so long? What can I do to avoid this?

EDIT:
Here is a fiddle of the page I'm running. I wasn't able to make a fiddle have the meta tag so it may have an extra 300ms delay on mobile devices. I recommend going through the steps "Got It! -> Fighter -> Accept -> Archery" After selecting "Archery" that is the slowest transition on the page. Why is that? I assume the layered opacities makes it very slow, but I still don't know for sure.
https://jsfiddle.net/2fLb1fd2/4/

```
.step {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 650px;
  background: rgba(16, 16, 16, 0.8);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms linear, top 300ms linear;
     -moz-transition: opacity 300ms linear, top 300ms linear;
       -o-transition: opacity 300ms linear, top 300ms linear;
          transition: opacity 300ms linear, top 300ms linear;
  opacity: 0;
  top: -100px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 30px auto 20px;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  color: white;
  pointer-events: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.step.showing {top:0;opacity:1;pointer-events:auto;}
```

Comment: "The process of stepping through those draw calls and filling out actual pixels into buffers that can be uploaded to the GPU for compositing." [per their timeline docs page](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/timeline)

Comment: As for why so long/what to do, how much is going on animation wise? Have a fiddle or anything for examination?

Comment: try to use css animation to see if it improves the performnce

Comment: @rahultyagi I am using BOTH in this scenario. The jquery animation works perfectly (It's just scrolling to the top of the page) I will cut out the jquery animation and see if that works any better.

Comment: @Madness I just edited my question to include the fiddle. It's not as slow as my site, I'm assuming that's because I'm using images for backgrounds on some of the divs.

Comment: If it is drawing opacity changes with images you can expect longer paint times

Comment: @StevenRogers I don't think this solves this particular issue, but try not to animate an element with both JS and CSS, because CSS will try to transition between individual JS animation steps, and the results are janky.

Comment: @StevenRogers also, there is always room to reduce performance issues by requiring less from your machine in particular scenarios. For exemple, I am used to remove superfluous transitions in smaller breakpoints to reduce visual lag in mobile devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here probably isn't opacity, opacity is a very cheap property (performance-wise) to animate with CSS. You are animating the `top` property however, this will trigger reflow each frame it is animated.

In order to make your animation smoother, you should animate `transform: translateY(x);` instead of the `top` property.

Comment: 4 months and a savior came to my rescue. I'll try what you're asking and I will get back to you to see if this works. Thanks for the answer!